# Working with files in another folder in rstudio ubuntu server

Tags: r, ubuntu, permissions, rstudio

I'm having problems working with different folders from withinRstudio. Description follows:
I have successfully installed Rstudio on my ubuntu server and all is working correctly. The starting working directory (using `getwd()` is `/home/amit`. I would like to source in  `srv/shiny-server/NEWFOLDER/Thingie.R`, but it gives the error:

#### Error in file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :

#### cannot open the connection

#### In addition: Warning message:

#### In file(filename, "r", encoding = encoding) :

#### cannot open file '/srv/shiny-server/NEWFOLDER/Thingie.R': No such file or directory

But I'm sure it's there. In fact, I can even open the file in Rstudio itself... but when I change it and try to fix it, it prevents save saying:

#### `This source file is read-only so changes cannot be saved`

So I figure it's a permission issue. I have tried in Linux to: `chmod 777 /srv/shiny-server/NEWFOLDER`, to no avail.

I can modify the file and source in the folder from R... so it's literaly only a Rstudio issue. What have I missed?

Comment: It looks like you gave the folder universal permissions, but not that individual file...try using chmod on the file as well.

Comment: Would I have to chmod every single file? It's probably 50 files that I'd have to modify, PLUS new files all the time... is there a way to just do all files at the same time?

Comment: Permissions for files and directories can be different. It might be you need to use `sudo` before the directory modification...`chmod 777 *` should apply to all contents current and future if memory serves me...

Comment: Very strange! After `chmod 777 *`  I could source the files in if I was in already `setwd()` to that folder, but NOT if I am `setwd()` in another folder and then I source in using the path. Very strange. I AM able to save. So I'll call this resolved... even tho it's a strange bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this with Rstudio server, and in my case related to the user profile in RSServer not having super user permissions. The easy thing to do is to create a new Rproject and store all of your files in that. That project will have the permissions of the user logged into RStudio and will be able to save under the user/home folder.